# Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.webkit.SafeBrowsingResponse"

Tags: android

I'm using WebView in my app while loading content warning logs is coming from logcat like below

```
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.webkit.SafeBrowsingResponse" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.android.chrome-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.android.chrome-1/lib/arm, /data/app/com.android.chrome-1/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
```

After That app crash again and again

```
04-25 09:46:49.219 26505-26505/com.abc W/google-breakpad: ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ###
04-25 09:46:49.219 26505-26505/com.abc W/google-breakpad: Chrome build fingerprint:
04-25 09:46:49.219 26505-26505/com.abc W/google-breakpad: 5.0.7lab
04-25 09:46:49.219 26505-26505/com.abc W/google-breakpad: 58
04-25 09:46:49.219 26505-26505/com.abc W/google-breakpad: ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ###
04-25 09:46:49.219 26505-26505/com.whence A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0xca480db0 in tid 26505 (com.whence)

                                                  [ 04-25 09:46:49.219   469:  469 W/         ]
                                                  debuggerd: handling request: pid=26505 uid=10314 gid=10314 tid=26505
```

Comment: are you sure your are using at least api level 27 (Andriod 8.1) ?

Comment: @casualcoder confirm using 27

Comment: app crashing on all api level??

Comment: @SuryaPrakashKushawah did you find a solution to this issue? I'm having the exact same issue myself

Comment: @roeiki11 this is kind of warning. It's handle in android oreo.

Comment: Same error on API 30. Still no solutions?

Answer (score 3):

Solution for the problem is:

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        view.getSettings().setSafeBrowsingEnabled(false);
    }

    WebSettings settings = view.getSettings();
    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Let me know if this doesn't work for you.

Comment: This codes doesn't fix the warning for me. It's just a warning though - I'm not experiencing any crashes.

Comment: It did fix it for us when we had the issues.

Answer (score 0):

```
 webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Try adding these lines. For more info https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html

Answer (score -4):

Since this is added in [API27](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/SafeBrowsingResponse.html), try setting SDK level as below:

```
min=27
target=27
compile=27
```

Comment: How can we set min=27 ..?

Comment: Setting minSdkVersion to 27 would mean it only runs on less than 1% of devices as of now. That's clearly not a good option.